# send integers in FormData

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, form-data

When I send an integer to the backend , I receive it as a string , I can't figure out why ?

```
var formdata = new FormData();

for (var i = 0; i < scope.user.values.length; i++) {
    formdata.append('values[]', scope.user.values[i]);
}
```

I receive values as string while they should be in integers

Comment: Relevant spec: [Interface FormData: For the purposes of interaction with other algorithms, an entry's type is "string" if its value is a string and "file" otherwise.](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-formdata)

Answer (score 15):

You actually cannot send `integers`, everything will be in string `format` and in `key-value` pairs when you use `formData`. Alternatively you can convert them to required `datatype` in backend.

**[Know more about FormData here](http://robertnyman.com/2013/02/11/using-formdata-to-send-forms-with-xhr-as-keyvalue-pairs/)**

Comment: What a silly feature...

Answer (score 4):

All values sent by HTML to the server-side are received as strings. You have to convert that data into integers in the backside, which shouldn’t be too difficult. If you specify which language your server-side is using maybe we could let you know how to convert string into integers in it.=, or ever better, you can look it up.

Comment: Thank You , do you Advice using formdata or there is a better solution ?

Comment: It depends on the data you wanna send to the server but general speaking formdata is fine. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try with solutions, It worked

In your controller update your variables as per your requirement

```
var a = []

$scope.b = [1,2,3,4]

for(var i =0 ; i < $scope.b.length; i++){ a.push(b[i]) }
```