# FormData converts numeric input field to string

Tags: javascript, html, json, form-data

I have REST backend and an HTML frontend.
I use forms on the frontend to send requests to the backend.
In order to do this, I use FormData to convert from the form object to a JSON object that I can send to the REST backend.

Heres the form

```
<form id="form">
    <label for="string">string:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="string" name="string" value="string"><br>
    <label for="number">number:</label><br>
    <input type="number" id="number" name="number" value="12"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

And the is is the function I use to convert the form to a json object:

```
window.onload = function(){
    const form = document.getElementById('form')
    form.onsubmit=send
}

function send(e){

    e.preventDefault()

    var data=new FormData(e.target)
    data=Object.fromEntries(data)
    console.log(data)


}
```

Unfortunately, FormData converts number inputs to strings, but the backend expects actual numbers. I know I could just reconvert them back to numbers manually for every form field, but this isn't the only form in the application and I would like to be able to reuse the same code for submitting to different endpoints.

```
{
  "string": "string",
  "number": "12"
}
```

So is there a way to either make FormData not convert the numbers to string, an alternative to FormData, or a way to autmatically reconvert strings to numbers, if the original input was a number input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything will be in string `format` and in `key-value` pairs when you use `formData`.
[Please check here for more explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33870800/send-integers-in-formdata)