# Why Postman cannot send the value as an Integer?

Tags: php, postman

I have an API and there is a file that will do a specific job.

This file will check the value type that was sent from the client side, if the value type was anything except Integer then will throw an error to the user.

**Here is an example:**

```
<?php
$userId = $_POST["userId"];

if (!is_int($userId) || $userId <= 0)
    exit(json_encode(array("REQUEST_STATUS" => 800))); //The number 800 will be translated in the client side to an unexpected error.

...
...
...
```

**Here is the value that I sent it using Postman:**

[image]

The PHP file always prints an unexpected error because the Postman sends the value as String.

I'm forced to use Postman to test the API because the client side is not ready yet to test the API.

Also, I can solve the problem by converting String to Integer temporarily in PHP but I think it is not easy if you have a lot of files to check.

Is there any way can I send an Integer value using Postman or any other way?

I have seen many similar questions to this question but that did not solve the problem.

Thank you.

Comment: What about is_numeric? or `if(!intval($userId))..`

Comment: To be clearer: `$userId = intval($_POST["userId"]??0); if(!$user_id)...`

Comment: @GeorgeG That will work but I'm looking for a way without modifying the PHP file. I don't know why Postman does not allow sending the value as an Integer!

Comment: Passing data using HTTP-parameters ($_GET, $_POST, ...) do not have a datatype. From HTTP's (and Postman's) point of view every parameter is a string - it depends on the server to handle it/convert it to the needed datatype.
Sending data using JSON supports some data-types... But this will require modificatins on client- and server-side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You trying to send payload using `form-data`.

Form data do not support values typing. [It is always string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33870881/13946204) (or plain text if say more accurate). It is same as query string: `https://URL/users?id=56&progress=99` where `56` and `99` are always strings.

Any web frameworks trying to cast `str` → `int` transparently under the hood.

You have to use `JSON` to be able get correct value type automatically.

Historically HTTP is a simple text protocol and here are no specifications how to separate variable types (in opposite to JSON format), you have to do it at backend.